# need to pass generic class in reflection get method

Tags: java, reflection

i am trying to invoking method using reflect, here i need to pass generic class "clazz" in the arguments.but i am not to achieve that..

here in example i tried  using  Class but  this is not working

```
     public void log(  Class<?> clazz,Throwable throwable,  String pattern) {
    Method method=  CommonsLogger.class.getMethod("info", Class<T>,String.class,Throwable.class);
    //try catch removed
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do like this. This should work,

```
CommonsLogger.class.getMethod("info", String.class, Throwable.class)
```

Comment: so this mean i can,t pass generic class in the getmethod..is that correct

Comment: Yes, precisely. Read on http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html